# Long-standing research question

Tags: word-usage

By "long-standing research question", I would like to mean a research question that has been there for a long time but not yet successfully attacked.

Any word(s) better than "long-standing" to use in this context?

Comment: It's a reasonable phrase to describe such a question.

Comment: *Long-standing* is perfectly common, idiomatic, and immediately comprehensible. Perfectly apt. You could also say an "*open* research question", but that doesn't necessarily connote that it's been around a while or received any meaningful attention. There are other adjectives such as *classic* or *seminal*, but those lack the connotation that the question is *still* open. You could say *intractable*, which has the connotations you want, but unfortunately also some others that you probably don't want (ie that the question will or can *never* be resolved).

Comment: In any case this question is interesting. +1. I'll be following the posted answers with interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider:

***A long-existing question***

> The Human Body and why it Works - Page 216 Raymond L. Powis - 1985
>
> CONCLUSIONS The journey from conception to birth is probably the most
>   compelling at its beginning and end, the moment of conception and the
>   physical adaptation of birth. And a single cell starts the journey.
>   **A long-existing question** in this ...

However, it's definitely less frequent than the original, which is also more "English," as in "having old Saxon roots":-)

Comment: Thanks. I think this may be a bit more widely used than long-unresolved that Edwin suggests. What do you think Edwin?

Answer (score 1):

The compound adjective **long-unresolved** exists (though it is too highfalutin for all but the most formal of registers). An example on the internet (tidied):

> Learn more about unresolved problem | (e) Science News (esciencenews.com/dictionary/unresolved.problem): a four-page report
>   [pdf] that claims to offer a solution, and as often can be the case
>   with long-unresolved problems, it is a simple one